# create phpMyAdmin foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using `phpMyAdmin`. I have two tables: `A`(Parent) and `B`(Child) with an `1<->N` relation. Both tables with `innoDB engine`. I want to create a `foregin key` in B that reference parent's table(A). i have created a `primary key` in A, id and also a `index` field in B. When i enter relations View in B i tried to set foreign key but fails.
B.index -> A.id. 
Error message: `No index Defined`(index)
I tried everything with no solutions

Thanks in advance

Comment: at structure view choose the `index` field and click the index logo below the structure table. That is how you index a field

Comment: I did that, but still no index defined message

Comment: Below the structure table there is a table called `Indexes`. Try check if you have the index there.

Comment: I have my index there, I did every step but nothing

Comment: can u share the DB structure

Comment: I did the SQL scrip and worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following alter query.

```
ALTER TABLE `B`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `B_A_id` FOREIGN KEY (`index`) REFERENCES `A` (`id`);
```

Comment: That works fine for me! only with SQL script, strange.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use **navicat** and working,
Trying with **navicat**, that is better and easy to manage mysql databases.
to find, in google type **navicat**.